# Create data frame using Nested partitioned file in S3 and load Data frame with partition column name in schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Nested S3 parition file As below :

```
s3://alex/covid/exposure_date=**2021-02-01**/aec600b87b9a467d9395d2f5c0e2eeaa.parquet
s3://alex/covid/exposure_date=**2020-05-01**/dec600b87b9a467d9395d2f5c0e2eeaa.parquet
s3://alex/covid/exposure_date=**2021-06-01**/efe600b87b9a467d9395d2f5c0e2eeaa.parquet
s3://alex/covid/exposure_date=**2021-08-01**/acd600b87b9a467d9395d2f5c0e2eeaa.parquet
```

Tried different ways to read :

Way 1:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3:/alex/covid/**/*.parquet")
```

Way 2:

```
df=spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup","true").parquet("s3:/alex/covid/covid_contact_mock_data.parquet/")
```

way 3:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://alex/covid//**/*.parquet")
```

I am expecting the partition column also one of the dataframe columns

In local tried to do the but getting error

```
df = spark.read.parquet("C:/Users/mthma/covid_contact_mock_data.parquet/exposure_date=2020-12-03/*")
```

the error:

```
Exception in thread "globPath-ForkJoinPool-6-worker-115" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with wildcards.

At least in the local case,
you can expand them to individual filenames with this:

```
folder = "C:/Users/mthma/covid_contact_mock_data.parquet/exposure_date=2020-12-03"
for file in glob.glob(f'{folder}/*'):
    df = spark.read.parquet(file)
    print(df.head())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob

S3 is different.
You should use the `boto3` library to query S3
for individual path names.